# access element html using selenium python

Tags: python, powerbi, css-selectors, click, selenium-webdriver-python

So I have an HTML code as follows. So in that HTML code, I want to retrieve the PODES button. Therefore, I've implemented the following code to retrieve the PODES button

`<transform _ngcontent-kts-c165="" data-automation-type="visualContainer" data-testid="visual-container" _nghost-kts-c161="" drag-resize-disabled="true" preserve-aspect-ratio="false" class="" style="height: 14px; width: 129px; transform: translate(11px, 294px); z-index: 10000;">     <div _ngcontent-kts-c165="" skip-children-focus="" extended-shortcut-scope="" toolbar-anchor="" class="visualContainer unselectable droppableElement ui-droppable readMode hideBorder paddingDisabled visualHeaderAbove" role="group" aria-roledescription="button" tab-order="43000" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" touch-action="auto" aria-label="PODES Page navigation . Click here to follow link">      <p _ngcontent-kts-c165="" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true" localize="VisualContainer_VisualsEnterHint_OnView" class="visualsEnterHint" id="visualsEnterHint-c25dfc424945c0d50057">Press Enter to explore data  </div> </transform>`

`state = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="PODES Page navigation . Click here to follow link"]')`

It successfully retrieves the PODES button, but when I perform 'state.click()', unfortunately, it doesn't successfully click the button on my Power BI dashboard. Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: You're finding a `<div>` element, which is not usually clickable.  I think this element may be only a **label** for the actual other element that you want to click on.